# how to store value of session into a variable

Tags: asp.net

Thanks a lot to all for helping me ...

Plz some one tell me .. How to assign value of session into a variable .
   I have a session which calculates no of rows in gridview . As below

session["cont"] = GridView1.Rows.Count ;
     Then in another function ,

I want to store this in Variable K ;

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:-

```
int K = (int)Session["cont"];
```